# 7.2VDC and 6VDC power supply from 12V transformer

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, schematics

I have a Arduino MEGA2560 clone, 5pcs of standard size servo motor (model MG996R) and 2 pcs of micro sized servo motors (model 9G), which I have to supply with DC power. And because the micro Servo 9G can use only 6V and the Arduino and standard Servos can use 7.2V, I'm quite confused about power supply of the whole board.

**Here's the table of operating voltages:**

Arduino mega2560 (recommended): 7-12VDC

Arduino mega2560 (limited): 6-20VDC

Servo MG996R: 4.8-7.2VDC (current at 6V: 0.5-0.9mA, stall: 2.5A)

Micro Servo 9G: 4.8-6VDC (current at 6V: 0.25A, stall: 0.96A)

I already have 4 new toroid transformers, which I attempt to use in this project, but still don't know what schematic should I use. I have:

2pcs primary: 230V secondary: 12V [S=30VA]

and

2pcs primary: 230V secondary: 11.8V [S=50VA]

The whole thing got stuck for me, because I don't know what schematic should I use to transform 12VAC or 11.8VAC to 7.2VDC **AND** is there a possibility to make from 1 toroid transformer 7.2V and 6V? If so, what schematic would be proper for this?

And in case if anything helps, I do have exact this [DC-DC modul](http://www.ebay.com/itm/201366364371?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT), which I can use at this project.

Would be really gratefull to whoever would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If full-wave rectify your 12V transformer and filter it you'll get around 15VDC. You could use 3 pieces of your DC-DC converter to give you 5.5V at 5A  (2 servo) + 5A (2 servo) + 4.5A (1 servo and 2 small servo) and use an LM7809 to preregulate for the Arduino.

The total consumption is more than 80W peak, so you could also split the supply using 2x 50VA transformers.

So- two 50VA transformers, two bridge rectifiers, two large filter capacitors, 3 DC-DC converters, and one LM7809 (with input and output capacitors). Using 4 DC-DC converters would allow you to split the load between the transformers more evenly, but probably okay as is. Capacitor value- maybe 22000uF/25V for about 1.5V ripple p-p.

Comment: You won't have enough current to run all the servos simultaneously at full torque with only one DC-DC. Consider running only some of them at once, with partial power. Then one xfmr, one bridge, one DC-DC for all servos and the 7809 for the Arduino. If the Chinese DC-DC fails 'on' it may destroy your servos.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs in your post, your worst-case scenario power draw (all 7 servos stalled, plus plwering the uC) is ~85W. None of your 4 xfmrs are rated for that load, so you will need to use @ minimum 2 of your xfmrs, or buy a bigger single xfmr.

Your controller board is spec'd to handle input voltages (limit) as high as 20V, so it could technically run directly from full-wave rectified (and capacitor smoothed) ~15VDC.

I would recommend pairing your 11.8V/50VA transformers together, after full-wave rectification. Power the Mega directly from the DC conditioning/smoothing cap (post rectifiers), then obtain a dc-dc converter *controller* with which (along with a switching MOSFET, a few resistors, a coil & a few caps) you can build your own converter, to run all 7 servos from its 6V output.

Comment: Hmm. I understand what you're saying, but unfortunatelly, that's impossible for me.

I mean, I can get components to build custom PCBs, but it's impossible for me to get 2 more DC-DC converters.

What about any casual schematic, that could just build up at home? I mean, what about a standard 12VAC to 7.2VDC scheme and using that DC-DC converter for the 6V on micro servos?

Or should I just use 6VDC on all of the servos? And power supply for arduino then?